# Ideas for replacing laptop keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I keep seeing laptop keyboards with non-optional number pads and it makes me cringe. Given that manufacturers seem to think numpads are OK (they're not), is it possible to somehow buy an ordinary keyboard, strip it and put in place of the one that's embedded in the laptop? I know laptop kbs are replaceable, so I'm wondering if anyone has done anything like this.

Comment: The form factor of the keyboard PCB is unlikely to fit in a laptop case.  If you can find one that does, more power to you,I doubt that keyboard PCB exists though.

Comment: This seems a bit of a rant against numpads on laptop keyboards. What is the actual problem you face which you are trying to resolve?

Comment: I will only ever buy laptops with number pads. I <3 my number pad.

Comment: There are lots of laptops without a numpad, buy one.

Comment: Possible?  Sure.  But probably not cheaply, and certainly not easily.  If you don't already have the electronics and machining tools, it would probably be cheaper to just buy the laptop you want.  You might take some inspiration from hardware modders like Ben Heck.

Answer (score 2):

Laptop keyboards cannot be replaced by desktop keyboards. Even if it was possible, the resulting hybrid laptop would be too uncomfortable to use. It makes more sense to plug a desktop keyboard into a USB port of the laptop and use it the way it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

More power to you, but it might be difficult.  Assuming some other keyboard can found to fit, (or can be made to fit, say by *sawing*, *cutting*, *drilling*, *epoxy*, etc.), odds are the cabling is non-standard and therefore incompatible, which means rewiring the cable connector.  But:

1. Laptop electronic schematics are often hard to come by.
2. The [flexible flat cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable) used to attach laptop keyboards IO boards or mainboards is hard to modify.  (One can't uproot one wire and plug it in another socket.)

Even that assumes the keyboard chipset of the new keyboard is electronically compatible with the laptop.  OTOH, there's only so many chipsets, so there probably exist many keyboards that *are* electronically compatible.

*Brute force* answer: Find a USB keyboard that can be made to fit in the same space as the original one, and wire it to the inside of a USB jack in the laptop, then block off that USB plug from the outside.

Comment:  I'd call the above difficulties part of a *connector conspiracy*, whether it's a real or de facto one is uncertain, but what is certain is all the e-waste that might be saved, or prevented, if laptop cases and internal peripherals, (screens, mobos, IO), had form factors and fittings as standardized as PC cases.